# Tailing already opened file in Perl

Tags: perl, file, io, multiprocessing, tail

I have one child process that writes into file some information dynamically. Sometimes I need to get `N` number of last lines of this file. But when parent process is reading file child will continue to write to it.
I have read that there is no sense to lock it and unlock, but I am not sure. I will not write anything from parent process, so I need to open it only for reading.
I have found module `File::Tail` , but didn't understand how to use it to get `N` number of last lines, please provide some simple example.

Also I need advice is it necessary to use locking in this case?

Comment: Why have you decided against locking? `flock` allows for shared (read) locks, and exclusive (write) locks. If you don't want to read whilst one process is writing, that sound exactly the tool for the job.

Comment: Please give an example reading last N lines of file using any module, I don't want to call shell function tail for this ,it is too expensive and heavy

Comment: @Sobrique: Did you tried do anything serious with `flock`? There are two file-locking mechanisms in Linux, both accessible from Perl and `flock` is one of them. But they are incompatible and works only with programs which use same locking mechanism. Hell no.

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'serious' - I have written scripts that do what the OP is trying to, and it's worked fine. Wouldn't suggest it for over NFS mounts or similar though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the last `N` lines of a files you can use the CPAN module `File::ReadBackwards`.

```
use File::ReadBackwards;

my $lastlines = File::ReadBackwards->new("file.txt");
print reverse map { $lastlines->readline() } (1 .. 2);
```

This will print last 2 lines of a file. Replace 2 with any number what you want.